# Borders applying font color in CSS

Tags: css

As CSS beginner I noticed that if you do not declare border color in a shorthand form, but before that you declare font color, that color will apply to the former as well e.g.

```
#crazyElement {color:red; border:1px solid;}
```

both will be red. Moreover, if you declare font color for the body, each border without declared color in shorthand form will apply that color also.

Is this normal? Maybe it's nothing special, but as a novice I just wanted to check...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is normal, and perfectly inline with the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-color-properties)

> If an element's border color is not specified with a border property, user agents must use the value of the element's 'color' property as the computed value for the border color.

via @BoltClock
[CSS3 Spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-color) and the [currentColor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentcolor) which is how it is defined.

Comment: @vucibatina If you are curious, you can search for any css property using the `site:w3.org` modifier in the search box to get very relevant results for any property.

Answer (score 0):

From the **[specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#foreground)**:

> This property describes the foreground color of an element's text
>   content. In addition it is used to provide a potential indirect value
>   (currentColor) for any other properties that accept color values. If
>   the ‘currentColor’ keyword is set on the ‘color’ property itself, it
>   is treated as ‘color: inherit’.

So yes, it's normal.

Comment: This quote by itself doesn't answer the question of why borders take on an element's text color by default (which is mentioned elsewhere in the spec).

Comment: It's explained, the `color` property value is used on some other elements whose color is not specified, though I'll admin Andrew's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Certain properties in CSS are automatically inherited.

Here's the list: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html